# C# : OAuth 2.0 authentication doesn't redirect for user consent

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, google-api, google-oauth

I'm working on a Web App that gets my users' gmails. For OAuth Authentication, I'm Making a Ajax call from UI to  HTTPHandler and from HttpHandler i'm making HttpWebRequest GET call to google server. I'm getting the response of complete HTML page (Google User login) that i'm rendering in my application's UI. And after logging in and clicking on the login, It does nothing. As per the document it actually have to redirect to the google page and after user's consent i should get the respponse to the Redirect_uri provided. Nothing of that sort is happening. Below is code block on my hanlder process request method.

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

```
String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Ffeed%2Fatom&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A50639%2FresponseHandler.ashx&approval_prompt=force&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";


        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webrequest.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
        Stream picasaResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(response.ResponseUri.ToString());
        StreamReader picasaReader = new StreamReader(picasaResponse);
        string picasaAPIResponse = picasaReader.ReadToEnd();
        Response.InnerHtml = picasaAPIResponse;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(response);
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect your users to the auth url (either using full page redirect or in a popup) instead of fetching the url.